# Delete files in a directory that match a regexp, using a Mac terminal

Tags: shell, rm, wildcards

How do I delete files in a directory that match a given regexp, or a similar solution, using a Mac terminal?

Comment: by mac terminal you mean OS X? if so I'm confused why this is tagged Linux.

Comment: removing filesystems tag and adding shell... filesystems should be more on a discussion about things like ext4, fat32, hfs, etc, and this seems to be asking about how to manipulate files on a shell.

Comment: @xenoterracide Thanks for refining my question!

Comment: removing terminal tag too.. think the 'terminal' tag should be reserved for questions regarding xterms, VT's and real connected terminals.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the `find` command.

Find all files (recursively) matching a regex: `find . -type f -regex '/ex/'`
Find all files (recursively) matching a regex and delete them: `find . -type f -regex '/ex/' -exec rm {} \;`

The brackets store the found pathname, and the backslash escapes the semicolon because it's passed to find; without escaping it, it would be consumed by the shell. If that went over your head, read the first two chapters of "Learning the Bash Shell".

Check the man pages for `find` for more options. There are a lot more ways to search.

Comment: nice answer, I just think this command will be easier to read `rm $(find . -regex '/ex/')`

Comment: use `rm '{}' +` the + is more xargs like behavior or something... really all I remember is that it's more efficient than doing `\;`.

Comment: @phunehehe I think the shell expansion you're doing is weird... and I'd question it's efficiency... I'd also wonder if it has a argument limit... (which is one of the things xargs was written to work around)

Comment: with + find will substitute more than one argument for {}, with ; just one. the \ is really only to protect the ; from the shell

Comment: @phunehehe: The major problem with `rm $(...)` is that it will not work if any of the file names contains whitespace characters or globbing characters `\\[*?`, because the shell expands them after substituting the `$(...)`.

Comment: They added the -delete action to GNU find in October 2004, which wraps up the common "-exec rm {} \;" incantation.  There's a section in the docs (http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_mono/find.html#Deleting-Files) where they walk through the reasons it's a better idea to use this than the old portable way, if you can get away with it. It answers the comment immediately above, having to do with whitespace, among many other concerns.  Good reading.

Comment: But be careful using `-delete` action. Placing it just after directory name will delete **ALL** files, i.e. `find . -delete -type f -regex '/ex/'`

Answer (score 4):

Very similar to jorelli's answer. This is what I use:

```
find . -regex '/ex/' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

The `-print0` and `-0` arguments cause find to output a char 0 separated list and xargs to perform the `rm` command in each element of the list, so paths with spaces are not a problem.