# Delete files recursively that DON'T match regexp

Tags: shell, find

I'm attempting to clean out a bunch of temporary files from a folder tree, but don't want to delete files that match some criteria, specifically executable files, .tpl files, and not the subfolder 'data'.

I see the question here

[Delete files in a directory that match a regexp, using a Mac terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1011/delete-files-in-a-directory-that-match-a-regexp-using-a-mac-terminal)

is almost what I'm looking for, but they have a regex they are trying to match, and I have a regex that I don't want matches. I can do this to find all of the files I don't to delete:

```
find . -executable -o -regex '.*\.tpl'
```

Is there a way to invert the matches, like -v does with regex?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way to invert the matches,
>   like -v does with regex?

Use **negation**(`!`):

```
find . -executable -o ! -regex '.*\.tpl' -exec rm -i {} \+
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the negation! From here I was able to figure out to use -a rather than -o, So the final command looks like `find . ! -executable -a ! -regex '.*\.tpl' -exec rm -i {} \+`, which matches my criteria of deleting everything except executables, subfolders, and .tpl files.

Answer (score 2):

A convenient way to run a command for everything except files matching certain conditions is to exploit `-o`'s short-circuiting behavior, e.g. `find -cond1 -cond2 -o -exec command` means “if `cond1` and `cond2` then do nothing, else execute `command`”.

```
find . -type f -executable -o -name '*.tpl' -o -exec rm -i {} \+
```

To exclude the `data` directory, use the `-prune` action, which means “skip this directory and don't recurse into it”. Use `-name data` to match all directories called `data`, or `-path ./data` to match only at the toplevel.

```
find . -type f -executable -o \
       -name '*.tpl' -o \
       -type d -name data -prune -o \
       -exec rm -i {} \+
```

---

Bonus: the same in zsh.

```
rm -i -- **/*~*.tpl~data/*(.^*)
```

- The [`~` operator](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Operators) excludes files matching certain patterns (you must do `setopt extended_glob` first).
- `**/` performs [recursive globbing](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Recursive-Globbing)
- The `.` [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) restricts the whole match to regular files, and `^*` excludes executable files (`^` negates the qualifiers that come after it; qualifiers are anded).